# Other cheap DSLR models vs Canon 1100D?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, photography-basics, low-budget

I'm tempted to buy my first DSLR camera. Local store here is selling the **Canon EOS 1100D** with EF-S 18-55mm F/3.5-5.6 DC III lens for **300 Euros**. Price is the main factor for me, but new technology would be better than old.

What i need is a short list of the low-budget level cameras on the market now, so that i could avoid wasting time in reading old reviews of old cameras that are no longer for sale or out-dated technically. I buy one camera and may shoot 10 years with it, so i would like to have a camera that is not outdated even before i start.

Comment: If you really want your camera to last ten years, skip the low-budget models.

Comment: On your edit: many review sites allow you to narrow down your search to current models. You can also just look at the date. Is the updated question really just how to do that?

Comment: I have been unsatisfied with my present camera, but have thought the upgrading to DSLR is simply too expensive. Now, after seeing the advertisement of the cheap Canon kit, I got the idea of buying one. So i'm very new to all this, but i'm learning fast as i go around internet. One of the first Google hits was this Photography site. Thought to ask for help with my search.. After looking thru several Canon and Nikon and Sony camera reviews, there's like a million different model/manufacturer combinations, and my head hurts already :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the product line ups change regularly your best bet would be to spend a few euro on a photography magazine or look up sites like [DPReview](http://www.dpreview.com) - they're chock full of reviews of the different cameras (especially at the lower end) and most reviews on the 1100d will make reference to competing models from other manufacturers.

When starting out your best bet is probably to look up the second hand websites and just see what you can get for your budget as you'll get a much better camera (if a generation or so older) for your money.

Comment: Thank you, i now found out there indeed is reference models with links to their respective reviews. Quite helpful. So far so good, i think i'll end up with [Nikon D3100](http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/d3100/spec.htm) instead of the Canon 1100D that i previously mentioned.

Comment: I found www.neocamera.com site today. Happy :)